# Infragistics on VisualStudio Team Services

Tags: build, cloud, azure-devops, infragistics

I have moved my local Buildserver to a VSTS Cloud and tried to build the solution.
Now, some projects use Infragistics for UI-Design. I had Infragistics installed on my local buildserver, but now I dont have the ability to install infragistics on to the VSTS-Cloud machine.

How can I get rid of this problem? Does anyone have any experience with Infragistics on VisualStudio TeamServices?

Thank you very much.